# Find coordinate on circumference

Tags: trigonometry

Consider a body starts moving in a circular motion with linear velocity 0.02 m/s and angular velocity 0.3 rads/s. If it's initial coordinates on Cartesian plane are x=5 and y=5, where would the body be after 5 seconds in terms of coordinates?

Comment: Without an initial direction there are infinitely many solutions to this question which form a circle. Do you look for the radius of this circle or is something missing in the problem description?

Comment: The body is moving in linear motion from origin (0,0) till (5,5). After (5,5) it takes a right turn

Comment: The angular velocity $\omega$ and the velocity $v$ are linked via the formula $\omega\cdot r=v$. Using this you can calculate the radius. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: About what point is the angular velocity?

Comment: @maxmilgram I want to know the location of the body after 5 seconds

Answer (score 1):

With the additional information from the comments the problem can be solved in the following way:

1. Calculate the radius $r$ of the circular motion by using $\omega\cdot r = v$. Here, $\omega$ is the angular velocity and $v$ is the velocity.
2. Calculate the center point of the circular motion.
3. Calculate the total angle covered in 5 seconds: $\varphi=\omega\cdot5$.
4. Use trigonometric functions or vector algebra to deduce the endpoint of the motion after 5 seconds.

Hope that helps! :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick solution. How to find out the center point of the circular motion?

Comment: You know the radius and you know that the mid point is orthogonal to the current direction of movement (at point $(5,5)$).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the motion in clockwise direction, we have

- $x-x_0=R\cos (\omega \cdot t)$
- $y-y_0=-R\sin (\omega \cdot t)$

with

- $\omega=0.3$ rad/s
- $v=\omega\cdot R=0.02$ m/s $\implies R=\frac {2}{30}$m

where $(x_0,y_0)$ are the coordinates of the center of motion lying on the line $y=x$ such that the distance form $(5,5)$ is equal to $R$.

Note that assuming the motion couterclock wise we can fine another valid solution.

Comment: The OP added some information in the comments below his post.

Comment: @maxmilgram Thanks, I see that now, then it seems moving clockwise!

Comment: from what I understood the center of motion is not at the origin. However the problem is very vaguely posed so I might be wrong. :-D

Comment: @maxmilgram Yes I think you are right! We can find the center of motion from the given conditions.